# Primefaces commandbutton clientside variable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm migrating richfaces to primefaces.

```
<a4j:commandButton id="editStatusButtonId" 
data="#{userTO.emailIdMandatoryStatus}" action="#UserAdministration.editStatusButtonAction}" oncomplete="if(data=='#{UserAdministration.configureEmailSettingStatus}')/>
```

I need any  replace attribute for data in primefaces commandabutton.

Comment: p:button is there in primfaces for button

Comment: @Panther button have not action attribute. I need action attribute and oncomplete to check  condition using client variable. If chance there is any way in p:commandbutton or any component

Answer (score 2):

It comes as the callback parameter in primefaces, on the [`RequestContext`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/requestContext.xhtml) component.

I'm going to "borrow" generously from the manual.

From your backing bean:

```
RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
requestContext.addCallbackParam("mandatoryStatus", userTO.emailIdMandatoryStatus); //isValid is the parameter
```

In your page, likely in a js function:

```
var mandatoryStatus= args.mandatoryStatus;
```

It has almost exactly the same semantics as in RF; the values are serialized as JSON, just as in RF; the data is made available on the `args` object, in RF - the `event.data`

Putting it all together, you can have:

```
<p:commandButton id="editStatusButtonId" action="#{UserAdministration.editStatusButtonAction}" oncomplete="if(args.mandatoryStatus=='#{UserAdministration.configureEmailSettingStatus}')/>
```